# How do I update the ng-model value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
    <form class="well form-search">
        <input type="text" id="reference" ng-model="reference" name="reference" class="input-large search-query">
        <button ng-click="getDetail(reference)" class="btn">Search</button>
    </form>
```

I have a function that updates the reference input and gives it focus, however the ng-click function on the button fails to fire

New to angular

```
function reffocus(ovalue) {
    $("#reference").val(ovalue);
    $("#reference").focus();
}
```

Comment: post the code for getDetail() (which hopefully is assigned to the $scope). also, what is that function reffocus()?  
 stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: Too broad. Have you declared an app, created a controller, and what does getDetail look like? Any errors in your console? Where is reference defined and assigned to $scope?

Comment: Also, if you're using angular, get that jQuery crap out of there. The purpose of Angular is to not have methods like that floating around. Use directives, that's what they're there for.

Comment: The variable in `ng-model` is automatically updated in the controller's `$scope` in a sense the variable is bound to the value of the input.  When you change the value of the input element you automatically change the value of the `ng-model` variable and vice versa.  Depending on what your `getDetail` function does you won't need to pass the `ng-model` variable it already available in the controller's `$scope` and thus available to the function `getDetail` which should be in the controller's scope.

Comment: I have determined the function Getdetail() does not activate until I make a change in the input field. Just adding a white space after automatically posting a value allows me to fire Getdetail(). It appears to be an onchange issue. Does the function on the button respect onchange()?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work (and [here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vbicxe?p=preview)):

**Note: if you already have `ng-app` and `ng-controller` setup you don't need to set them here.*

```
<form class="well form-search" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <input type="text" id="reference" ng-model="reference" name="reference" class="input-large search-query">
        <button ng-click="getDetail()" class="btn">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.getDetail = function() {

        // $scope.reference will be initialized by ng-model
        console.log($scope.reference);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think it is a different issue. The function does not fire, I can only think it is because it does not realise the input has changed, as soon as I add a space it runs. Do I need to scope.$apply ?

Comment: which function? The jquery `reffocus` function?  How are you invoking it?

Comment: Onclick in the first <td> of a table, carrying the value of that column.     

    $("#table_div tr td:first-child").each(function() {
        $(this).html('<a href="#" onclick="reffocus('+ $(this).html() +')">' + $(this).html() + '</a>');
    });

Comment: I'm confused.  You may have to update your question with all the code so we can see the entire picture clearly.  I guess I'm not totally clear on what you are trying to achieve.  :)

Comment: No problem, my first post. I will learn how to phrase my questions!

Answer (score 0):

Notice how Davin did  not use jQuery in his solution.  If you are new to angular, you need to temporarily drop jQuery.  It is a crutch and will really slow down your learning process.  You might get a little frustrated but hang in there. You can do a lot of jQuery stuff with angular.  I know it really helped me in the beginning.  Now I use jQuery only when it is appropriate.

Comment: I'm currently having difficulty with the $scope of variables, thats the only reason for defaulting to jquey. Deadline is an issue, I will revert to Angular over time.